# Assign just constructed unnamed value using move assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I want to assign just constructed **unnamed(I mean "created in place without declaration". Fix me, please, if it isn't correct terminology.)** container with a big number of elements to another container, using move assignment.

Should I write this way:

```
vector_used_before = std::move(vector<double>(100, 1.0));
```

Or simply:

```
vector_used_before = vector<double>(100, 1.0);
```

It's obvious that compiler can always use move assignment in this case, since we can't use created object anymore. But how does it really work?

Comment: The term you're looking for is 'temporary'.

Comment: Thank you. So, I suppose, if it's 'temporary', compiler is going to use move assignment here? Or not? This still isn't obvious.

Comment: Yes, temporaries are by definition r-values, so the compiler is free to use move assignment; `std::move` has no effect since all it does is turn a reference into an r-value reference (which it already is).

Comment: @Cameron Nitpicking semantics: A temporary is an object, not an expression, and therefore neither an lvalue or an rvalue; value category applies to expressions. A temporary is always (IIRC) created to hold the value of an rvalue expression, but conflating temporary-ness with rvalue-ness makes it impossible to describe lifetime extension, e.g., `auto&& foo = vector<double>(100, 1.0);`. `vector<double>(100, 1.0)` is an rvalue expression, the compiler creates a temporary object within which to store that value, but `foo` is then an lvalue expression that denotes the same object.

Comment: @Casey: I stand corrected :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector<double>(100, 1.0)` is already an rvalue, so these two snippets of code do exactly the same thing - move assignment. The correct answer is therefore "use the shortest one":

```
vector_used_before = vector<double>(100, 1.0);
```

Comment: Why is it rvalue? Constructor doesn't return any result. So, it isn't rvalue just because it was returned by a function. Is there any guarantee that constructor produces rvalue?

Comment: @Vasily `vector<double>(100, 1.0)` is a "*simple-type-specifier* followed by a *parenthesized-expression-list*" as described in C++11 5.2.3/1, it "is equivalent in effect to the declaration `T t(x1, x2, ...);` for some invented temporary variable `t`, with the result being the value of `t` as a prvalue."

Comment: OK than. That's the answer. Thanks.